# How to dynamically set Cache mode in Lookup

Tags: ssis

The first time our SSIS packages run they do a full load, and incremental loads afterwards. All Lookups are using Full cache, but it may not be handy for incremental loads, as some of the Lookup tables contain millions of records, and the incremental load may be small.

Is it possible to dynamically set, based on some parameter, whether a Lookup should use Full Cache, Partial Cache or No Cache?

**Solution**

Because the database and SSIS packages are on the same server, partial cache with indexes on the lookup columns is as fast as full cache for full loads, and even faster for incremental loads.

Comment: Marking it as fav. Would love to know the answer. However, did you try incremental over full cache ? How much difference did you observe ?

Comment: I havent tried Incremental but its worth giving a shot. Will get back to you with the results.

Comment: The database and SSIS packages are on the same server. Partial cache for full loads is as good as full cache, when there are indexes on the lookup columns. And its better for incremental loads. Thanks for the suggestion @PrabhatG

Comment: Glad it worked. We have been using full cache over millions of rows, without significant performance loss (db-ssis are on same server, same as yours)

Answer (score 0):

I can't see a way to do this, but potential alternatives would be:

1. Build two different data flow tasks, one for each cache type, and then use a variable/logic to decide which one to run by setting expressions on your precedence constraints.
2. Use an SQL statement from a variable as your Lookup connection, and select only the records you need, e.g., if it's based on a date range or something like that. You could then build the SQL statement before each execution.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. #1 requires that both Data Flow tasks are updated whenever there is a change. This is a little risky and with 100-200 packages, we'll have a hard time telling if all Tasks are in sync. #2 We can't beforehand determine which rows on the lookup table will be needed. A change in the source table may map to a row in the lookup table that hasn't changed.

Comment: No worries - how many records are you loading in your full load? If the lookup data is well-indexed then no cache can still be quite quick.

Comment: The bigger tables have between 2 million and 30 million rows. There are clustered indexes on all primary keys. It may be worth while waiting a little longer for the full load to complete with no cache. I'll have to test this :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a trick I am using. Create 2 lookups. First is a lookup with full cache and redirect on no match. Its no match branch goes into the second lookup that is exactly the same but in partial cache mode. The no match policy on this one is what you actually need. Match results from both lookups combine back together in a union all.

Now the tricky part. You go to out of the dataflow to control flow that contains it. When you select that dataflow element, in its properties you can find expressions. In those expressions you find the following looking entry [].[SqlCommand]. There you should build an expression for your lookup that will add a false condition to it in case when you want to use the partial lookup.

Here is a simple example. Let's say you have IsFullLookup boolean variable that you set to true when you are having a large initial load, and to false on small incremental loads. And let's say your lookup query looks the following way.

```
SELECT Value, Key FROM MyLookupTable
```

Then the expression may look something like this

```
"SELECT Value, Key FROM MyLookupTable" + ( @[User::IsFullLookup] ? "" : " WHERE 0=1" )
```

How this works. If your IsFullLookup variable is true then the query remains unchanged. It performs full load to cache, and all matching values go straight to union all. Non-matching values go to the partial cache lookup. That's the downside of this method, so it might be not best if you have too many non-matching values on full loads.

If your IsFullLookup is false, full cache produces 0 rows quite quickly. All lookups also produce no match very quickly and your rows are all redirected to the partial cache lookup that does its job the regular way. In this case you get pure partial cache lookup with minimal overhead.

This technique makes your packages uglier than before. But if you work with large lookup tables it is totally worth it. In your everyday load you are not spending extra time and memory on large lookups. But in rare case when you need a full (or just a large) load your partial cache does not become a disaster.